# How to convert ndarray to spark dataframe for mlflow prediction?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, mlflow

I have a trained model, and test input from mnist

```
import mlflow
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, col
logged_model = 'runs:/myid/myModel'


loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf(spark, model_uri=logged_model, 
result_type='double')

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

shape of x_test is `(10000, 28, 28)`

However I am having trouble converting ndarray from mnist to spark dataframe so that I can do prediction for my model

```
mydf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(x_test).map(lambda x: 
[x.tolist()]).toDF(["Doc2Vec"])

output = mydf.withColumn('predictions', loaded_model(struct(*map(col, mydf.columns))))
```

when I try to output the result

```
output.show(10)
```

I got

```
An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).'.
```

What am i missing here?

Here is my training model

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import uuid

    BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
    BATCH_SIZE = 64

    def make_datasets():
        (mnist_images, mnist_labels), _ = \
            tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path=str(uuid.uuid4())+'mnist.npz')

        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
            tf.cast(mnist_images[..., tf.newaxis] / 255.0, tf.float32),
            tf.cast(mnist_labels, tf.int64))
        )
        dataset = dataset.repeat().shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
        return dataset

    def build_and_compile_cnn_model():
        model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'),
        ])
        model.compile(
            loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001),
            metrics=['accuracy'],
        )
        return model

    train_datasets = make_datasets()
    options = tf.data.Options()
    options.experimental_distribute.auto_shard_policy = tf.data.experimental.AutoShardPolicy.DATA
    train_datasets = train_datasets.with_options(options)
    multi_worker_model = build_and_compile_cnn_model()
    multi_worker_model.fit(x=train_datasets, epochs=3, steps_per_epoch=5)
```